# Values from list into title (R)

Tags: r

I have created a script which reads values from two files and stores the names of the files in a two chr vector-variable (called *percent.names* and *points.names*), and then plots them. I want to save the figure with the name of one of the files, but I do not know how to get the i-th value of a chr vector into title.

```
path = 'D:/.../Scatters/'

puntos.names <- dir(path, pattern ="puntos.txt")
porcentaje.names <- dir(path, pattern ="porcentaje.txt")

for(i in 1:length(puntos.names)){
  coop = scan(porcentajes.names[i], sep=",", dec=".")
  cost = scan(puntos.names[i], sep=",", dec=".")

  *HERE*
  png(filename='D:/.../Scatters/')

  plot(cost,coop,log="",pch=20,col="black",xlim=c(0,5),ylim=c(0,1),lwd=0.5,xlab="points purchased per round",ylab="individual cooperation frequency")

  "SOME MAGIC"

  dev.off()
}
```

I know how to do it in Python, but I do not manage to make it in R.

In Python it should be something like this:

```
plt.title('COMP P %.2f ' %percent_name[i])
```

Comment: you want tio know the function that sets the title of a plot? its simply title(). read more through ?title

Comment: or add parameter  `main = percent_name[i]` to `plot`.

Comment: I want to extract a value from a vector and put it in a string which will be the title of the plot.